# How to write list data to Firestore, read and update

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I get the data in the list from TextFormField to Firebase Database and how can I read it and display it on the screen and update it?

[image]

I get it as below, but I could not get it from the TextFormField, I read it from the console, but I could not update it.

```
final docData = {     
  "list": [
    {
      "id": "data1",
      "amount1": "2000",
    },
    {
      "id": "data2",
      "amount1": "2500",
    },
    {
      "id": "data3",
      "amount1": "3500",
    }
  ],     
};

db
  .collection("data")
  .doc("one")
  .set(docData)
  .onError((e, _) => print("Error writing document: $e"));
```

Comment: What isn't working about the code you shared? Is there an error mssage?

Comment: The codes I shared are working, there is no problem. I am asking how can I send the list data from TextFormField and how can I update it.

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service but we are happy to help with existing code. Can you share the code you've attempted?

Comment: dear Jay Thank you for your interest. The main problem is Add data and get data to FieldValue.arrayUnion in Flutter with Cloud FireStore.
How do I get the data structure similar to the data in the list from the TextEditingController and add data it to Firebase. Also how do I get data from Firebase and show it on the screen.
Thank you for your help